# How to Make the total work of SubMonitor as IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN in eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have created **SubMonitor** by **SubMonitor.convert(monitor,IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN )**. Even though i am providing the total work as UNKNOWN, internally it assigns 1000 as total number of ticks(refer SubMonitor.java). how to make the total work as UNKNOWN in this case?

Comment: Note, that `UNKNOWN` is different from zero. Where/how do you provide the total work as zero?

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have corrected my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubMonitor` doesn't really support unknown progress.

You can either stick with just using `IProgressMonitor` and not converting or you can use code like this:

```
void unknownProgress(IProgressMonitor monitor)
{
    SubMonitor subMonitor = SubMonitor.convert(monitor);
    while (hasMore())
     {
        // Use 1% of the remaining space for each iteration
        processNext(subMonitor.setWorkRemaining(100).split(1));
     }
}
```

as suggested in [this article](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Progress-Monitors/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response.what about using SubProgressMonitor in place of SubMonitor?

Comment: It is marked as deprecated but you can still use it in the same way as before.